# Question on Multiple Regression (vs multiple single regression models)

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I have a pretty basic psychology fMRI study and we're trying to identify brain areas correlated with performance on a specific task.

We have one dependent variable, and measurements for each brain area for 54 areas. The results are highly correlated with age and gender.

Initially, I've corrected each brain area's value for age and gender by normalizing vs the mean for gender and normalizing vs the predicted values from a linear regression for age. Then, I ran multiple linear regressions (one for each brain area), calculated p-values and corrected with bon-ferroni. I feel like this is probably an adequate analysis since bon-ferroni should over-correct, but was wondering if there was a better way. Doing it this way resulted in more than 20 significant areas for one of our analyses. This seems like a lot when there's 54 areas. Additionally, our performance metric isn't a normal distribution.  It's kind of a reverse gaussian, but there are more top-end performers than bottom end (so a left skewed reverse gaussian?):
[image: Distributions]

Doing a logit transform makes the data look more normal, but it still fails a shapiro normality check. Additionally, perfect scores aren't able to be properly tranformed.  Setting the accuracy to .9999 results in transformations to ~4:
[image]

I ran a multiple regression but there's a lot of multi-collinearity due to the high number of brain areas. The general rule seems to be 10 subjects per variable in the regression, but we only have 79 subjects.

I ran a principal components regression but that's not very helpful since it groups together completely unrelated brain areas. There were a couple significant principal components, but that doesn't mean much as we are trying to identify specific brain areas.

It seems like in the literature, multiple regression is handled by only using a small number of apriori regions in the multiple regression. We do have apriori areas, but that seems like a silly way to do it. I feel like there will always be at least one significant area even if the R^2 value isn't great. That doesn't really mean the significant region is actually correlated with your data (but maybe I'm wrong in this assumption). On top of that, we have data for all of these brain regions. It would be nice to report on areas that we found to be correlated, even though they weren't in our hypothesis.

TLDR: What's the best way to find highly correlated brain areas in an analysis with a single dependent variable, 54 regions (independent variables), along with gender+age effects and a non-normal distribution?

Comment: I would say PCA is a good approach, you could check which brain regions are weighted high on the important PC's and that not only tells you which regions are important but how they are clustered to give a good performance. You can use other distributions such as Gamma that can handle skewness in your data. And normality assumption should be checked on the residuals not the marginal distribution of the response variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The issue with PCA is the principal components just explain the variety between the brain areas. This would be a fine method for something like brain activation, but we're measuring diffusivity which is not correlated in any way between similar functional areas.
The main principal component is almost entirely Gender/Age when those are included since that's going to be the biggest influence on structural changes between brains.
From there, the principal components all have random unrelated areas at semi-evenly dispersed positive through negative weights.

Comment: Have you considered regression + regularization (L2 not L1)?